# Possible to increase the width of empty left-edge padding within the Notepad++ edit area?

Tags: notepad++, user-interface, usability, readability, ux

In Notepad++, the user can adjust the width of the frame around the edit area by changing the value of *Preferences -> Editing -> Border Width*.

But for standard text files, I find that having the left edge of the text so close to the frame makes the text harder to read.

Is there any way to increase the width of the empty padding *within* the edit area for standard text files?

Comment: I'm not aware of any setting in vanilla Notepad++ though enabling folder margin and setting to simple may help a little (`Preferences->Editing->Folder Margin Style->Simple`)

Comment: A quick skim through the available plugins didn't show anything. A possible workaround is to create a macro to insert some number of spaces before each line, (and another to remove them) though this will probably be more painful than finding a more configurable editor

Comment: @HugoBuff Thanks Hugo.  I gave it a try, but I don't see any difference when setting the Folder Margin Style to *Simple*, do you?

Comment: If it was previously set to None, you get an extra 1 character of space between the line-numbers and your text. I suggested simple because it's the most minimalistic and it's the closest thing to an empty space I could find

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to increase the space before the text, though I have not found a way to control the colour of this space yet.

The margins in Notepad++ can be [changed using macros](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Margins). Open up your `shortcuts.xml`. This can be found in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\shorcuts.xml`. The copy in `Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\...` is a template.

Add the following macro inside the `<Macros>` node of the xml then restart Notepad++.

```
    <Macro name="Increase Margin" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="39">
        <Action type="0" message="2242" wParam="3" lParam="20" sParam=""/>
    </Macro>
```

This will create a new macro with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> that sets the width of the Fold margin to 20px (`lParam`). The shortcut can be changed easily from within Notepad++ by going into `Macro->Modify Shortcut` and changing the buttons required. This will need to be run
each time that Notepad++ is started, however.

Further info  on how to tweak the macro can be found in the above link